# Place inner div outside the super parent - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a requirement to place an inner child element outside the super parent. I want the super parent and child relationship to be retained and with `overflow: auto` enabled on the super parent. Here below is the view I am getting:

[image]

The desired condition is as below:

[image]

I am attaching the code snippet in the below, can you please help? Thank you.

```css
*{
  color : white
}

.superParent{
 overflow : auto;
 background-color : red;
 padding: 1rem;
  position : relative;
  padding: 1px;
} 

.parent{
  background-color : green ;
  padding : 1rem;
  position : relative
}

.child{
  background-color : grey;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -60px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="superParent">
     Super Parent :: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic laudantium ex ab architecto totam pariatur earum. Neque repellat, fugit porro similique repellendus sint ducimus commodi, at ratione ullam magni reiciendis expedita magnam animi mollitia perspiciatis, perferendis voluptas autem placeat facilis. Ratione voluptas voluptatibus molestias libero consequatur architecto perspiciatis dolore qui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic laudantium ex ab architecto totam pariatur earum. Neque repellat, fugit porro similique repellendus sint ducimus commodi, at ratione ullam magni reiciendis expedita magnam animi molli
     <div class="parent">
        parent
       <section class="child">
           child
       </section>
     </div>
   </div>
   <br/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more how the superparent is supposed to scroll in the required scenario? What would there be to scroll? Is there something else that is giving it a height definition for example?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking is possible; every descendant of an `overflow: auto` will be included in the scroll, unless it is `position: fixed` which I don't think works for you.

Are you sure you have to keep that markup?

Comment: Thanks @Jean for your reply. I am working on an existing project which has the markup done as such and I was asked to work on this possibility. Wanted to check with you all (developer community) if that's possible. Thank you.